# Laravel - Check if value is present in array

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections, contains

Why does this code return false every time?

```
$lics = collect(['lic100' => auth()->user()->lic100, 'lic250' => auth()->user()->lic250, 'lic500' => auth()->user()->lic500]);
$licsowned = $lics->filter()->keys();
$haslicense = property_exists($licsowned, $data['lictype']);
```

$licsowned:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#367 ▼
 #items: array:3 [▼
  0 => "lic100"
  1 => "lic250"
  2 => "lic500"
 ]
}
```

$data['lictype'] has the value `lic250`

I also tried with in_array() but it gave the error message that the value must be an array and I passed an object.

Comment: So, did you try the `contains()` method of `Collection` instance? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-contains

Comment: I did it, man. :)

Comment: @OlegNurutdinov please elaborate a little bit the answer, else i have to accept the other one since it contains more informations and an example. thanks.

Comment: Updated it. Should bo better than was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `contains()` method of `Collection` instance.

For example:

```
$collection = collect(['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100]);

$collection->contains('Desk');
```

Or, in your task:

```
$lics = collect(['lic100' => auth()->user()->lic100, 'lic250' => auth()->user()->lic250, 'lic500' => auth()->user()->lic500]);

$lics->contains('lic250');
```

More info:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-contains

Answer (score 3):

Your `$licsowned` variable is a collection. You can use `contains()` method. Example:

```
$licsowned->contains('lic100')
```

More information about `contains()`: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-contains